# Get Dates based on Current Date and List of Week Days

Tags: c#, date

I have something odd requirement. I have Current Date and List of Week Days. And I want next all possible date till the target date.
For i.e. `Today, its 22-04-2014 And Tuesday. Target date is 15-05-2014`
**I have 2 week days, Monday and Thursday.** So code should find near by Week Day, which will be Thursday here. So It should return date of **Thursday which is 24-04-2014**. Now, next turn is of Monday which comes from List. So now, It should return date of **Monday which is 28-04-2014**.
It should keep repeating till the target date.
So, final result will be

```
24-04-2014,
28-04-2014,
1-05-2014,
5-05-2014,
8-05-2014,
12-05-2014
```

Please help me to get this type of result. Here, Monday and Thursday is not fixed. It can be any Day and any number of Day.

Comment: Did you try anything? if it is please post the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update :** Link to the working example - [**Example**](http://ideone.com/sU1IJX)

You can try this code, i have tested it and working correctly

```
private List<DateTime> ProcessDate(DateTime dtStartDate, DateTime targetDate)
        {
            DateTime dtLoop = dtStartDate;
            //dtRequiredDates to hold required dates
            List<DateTime> dtRequiredDates = new List<DateTime>();
            for (int i = dtStartDate.DayOfYear; i < targetDate.DayOfYear; i++)
            {
                if (dtLoop.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday || dtLoop.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Thursday)
                {
                    dtRequiredDates.Add(dtLoop);
                }
                dtLoop = dtLoop.AddDays(1);
            }
            return dtRequiredDates;
        }
```

You may have to enhance this codes so that it doesn't throw any exception based on the requirement.

**UPDATE 2:**
You can have another method which will accept the days of week as follows

```
private List<DateTime> ProcessDate(DateTime dtStartDate, DateTime targetDate, List<DayOfWeek> daysOfWeek)
        {
            DateTime dtLoop = dtStartDate;
            List<DateTime> dtRequiredDates = new List<DateTime>();
            for (int i = dtStartDate.DayOfYear; i < targetDate.DayOfYear; i++)
            {
                foreach (DayOfWeek day in daysOfWeek)
                {
                    if (dtLoop.DayOfWeek == day)
                    {
                        dtRequiredDates.Add(dtLoop);
                    }
                }
                dtLoop = dtLoop.AddDays(1);
            }
            return dtRequiredDates;
        }
```

Here is the [**Example**](http://ideone.com/EzRyAJ)

Hence you can pass any number of week days as you wish.

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you, but here, monday and thursday is not fixed. it can be any days and any number of days. what is the solution for this ?

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working cool. I need to check Days dynamic but I will do it. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
List<DayOfWeek> listOfDays = new List<DayOfWeek>{DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Thursday};
var end = new DateTime(2014,05,15);
var day = DateTime.Now.Date;
while (day < end)
{
    day.AddDays(1); // adds +1 days to "day"
    if (listOfDays.Contains(day.DayOfWeek)) Console.WriteLine(day.Date.ToString());
}
```

(I can't test the code right now, so maybe you need to modify a little ;-)

Comment: here, Monday and Thursday is not fixed. It can be any week days and it can be number of days. so how to maintain it ?

Comment: In what form do you have the weekdays? You should be able to put an integer into the listOfDays too, like `{1,4}`, where 0 = Sunday, 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, ...

Comment: Could be you'll have te explicitly cast ist like this: `List<DayOfWeek> days = new List<DayOfWeek>{(DayOfWeek)1, (DayOfWeek)3};`